# $compile within $compile not getting applied

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive which takes in an array of container objects and $compiles a new container directive for each container and each nested container. It also compiles a resize handle before all containers except the first child. The link function looks like this:

```
//scope.dock is retrieved from a factory
scope.initContainers = function () {
        var prevScope;

        for (var i = 0; i < scope.dock.containers.length; i++) {
          var newScope = scope.$new(true);
          newScope.container = scope.dock.containers[i];
          var newElement = '<panel-container class=\"' + scope.dock.containers[i].axis + '" ></panel-container>';
          var newTemplate = $compile(newElement)(newScope);

          if (i > 0) {

            var sizerScope = scope.$new(true);
            sizerScope.containerOne = prevScope;
            sizerScope.containerTwo = newScope;

            var sizerElement = '<resize-handle class=\"' + scope.dock.containers[i].axis + '"></resize-handle>';

            var sizerTemplate = $compile(sizerElement)(sizerScope);

            element.append(sizerTemplate);
          }
          element.append(newTemplate);

          if (scope.dock.containers[i].containers.length > 0) {
            generateContainers(scope.dock.containers[i], newScope, newTemplate);
          }
        }
        return scope;
      };

      scope.sizeContainers = function () {
        scope.$broadcast('size-containers');
      };


      var generateContainers = function (value, parentScope, parentElement) {
        var prevScope;

        for (var y = 0; y < value.containers.length; y++) {
          var newChildScope = parentScope.$new(true);
          newChildScope.container = value.containers[y];


          var newChildElement = '<panel-container class=\"' + value.containers[y].axis + '" ></panel-container>';
          var newChildTemplate = $compile(newChildElement)(newChildScope);

        if (y > 0) {
            var sizerScope = parentScope.$new(true);

            sizerScope.containerOne = prevScope;
            sizerScope.containerTwo = newChildScope;

            var sizerElement = '<resize-handle class=\"' + value.containers[y].axis + '"></resize-handle>';

            var sizerTemplate = $compile(sizerElement)(sizerScope);
            parentElement.append(sizerTemplate);
         }
         parentElement.append(newChildTemplate);

        if(typeof value.containers[y].containers !== 'undefined') {
            if (value.containers[y].containers.length > 0) {
              generateContainers(value.containers[y], newChildScope, newChildTemplate);
            }
          }
          prevScope = newChildScope;
        }
      };
      scope.initContainers().sizeContainers();
```

My problem is that the first child layer compiles but the second one does not. It does, however, work when I add `scope.$apply` to the end of `generateContainers`. Unfortunately for some reason it is skipping the first child element for each container and throwing a 'digest in progress' error.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this to compile?

And could someone explain why `scope.$apply()` is compiling the second layer only after I explicitly call it, even when `$digest` is already running?

Comment: so congested code..don't understand why you created childscope everytime?

Comment: It is so I can inject values into the scope on compile. They are all meant to have their own child isolate scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by getting rid of `initContainers` (since it was exactly the same as `generateContainers`) and moving that function to the container directive as well. That way the root directive wasn't trying to compile everything.